# NodeJS Selenium using WebElements returned from findElements

Tags: python, node.js, selenium

I am completely new to Node.js and am currently trying to re-write some of my Python code into it.

I have the following snippet in Python where `driver` is my `webdriver` instance.

```
tabs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="className"]') 
for tab in tabs:      
    print(tab.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text)
```

My Node.js interpretation of this code is

```
tabs = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath('//div[@class="className"]'));        
for ( var tab in tabs ) {           
    console.log(tab.findElement(webdriver.By.css('span')).getText());
}
```

However I am getting the error

> TypeError: tab.findElement is not a function

What is causing this?

I must admit, I feel like I'm slightly missing the key point of Node.js but maybe this example may help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I dig into the selenium source code for [`findElement()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/webdriver/atoms/inject/find_element.js#L41) I see it can take an `opt_root` as parameter. The doc about it says:

> @param {?{ELEMENT: string}=} opt_root The WebElement reference for the
>    *     element to perform the search under. If not specified, will use
>    *     {@code document} for the target page.

So I think that instead of `tab.findElement(webdriver.By.css('span')` you'll have to do:
`driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css, 'span', tab)`

**Note:** I don't know precisely how `node.js` works. I just went through the source code so I'm not sure it will work.